# How can I record an RTMP stream in real time?

Tags: flash, video-streaming, recording, audio-streaming, rtmp

How can I record an RTMP stream (Adobe Flash video and audio) which is currently playing, as-is?

I have a very long video which can't be downloaded by any downloader I tested. So I want to scroll it to the desired position, playback and record only a small part.

Comment: Have you tried rtmpsuck (not offensive word)?

Comment: I don't understand how to use it. Suppose I set RTMP server name in `hosts` to localhost. Now what? How `rtmpsuck` will know where to forward a connection? Also in my case Flash applet accesses RTMP server by it's IP address.

Comment: Do you have the full URI of the stream?

Answer (score 2):

If you're finding it difficult to use rtmpsrv.exe and rtmpsuck.exe from the command line, I recommend NirSoft's [RTMPDumpHelper](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/rtmp_dump_helper.html):

> RTMPDumpHelper is a small utility that can help you to easily download RTMP video/audio streams. By combining this utility and the proxy server of [RTMPDump toolkit](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/), you can simply open a Web page containing RTMP video stream in your favorite Web browser, and while watching the video, it'll be saved to your disk automatically as .flv or .mp4 file.

[image: 1]

I've successfully used it to record complete RTMP streams, but never tried a partial download so far. If the underlying rtmpsrv.exe/rtmpsuck.exe proxies support it though then what you want to do should be possible.

Comment: I see no any reaction in my case. When I open a video in browser (Chrome) nothing happens. May be it writes a file somewhere but does not say me about it. This is not Youtube video btw, this is some custom content.

Comment: Can you try with Firefox or even IE instead?

Comment: Ok, the applet is not compatible with FF, while it runs with IE and RTMPDumpHelper als runs, but stops recording once I scroll time slider. I can't record entire stream since it is very long.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Web Stream Recorder](http://www.webstreamrecorder.com) tool, it works for me for most RTMP broadcasts, but not for all.